# Solve Json of PGObject in Solr 7.3.0

Tags: json, parsing, solr, split

I'm trying to perform a delta import (full-import works) of documents that contains a PGobject (structured as a Json). Solr gives me a warning such as:

org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: TransactionLog doesn't know how to serialize class org.postgresql.util.PGobject; try implementing ObjectResolver.

I found this link from Solr reference: https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/transforming-and-indexing-custom-json.html#TransformingandIndexingCustomJSON-TipsforCustomJSONIndexing.
It can be usefull in my case but using windows i don't know how to use it.

The structure is as follow:

{\"key\": \"value\",
  \"key\": \"value\",
  \"key\": \"value\",
  \"key\": \"value\",
  \"key\": \"value\"}"

Anyone had this problem or give me an hand?